# Cannot write to database - what's wrong?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

Hey guys I'm trying to write to the database but it's not working.  My database has 4 fields, ID, A, B, and C.  They are all of TEXT type and the database table is Table1.

Here is my code, can you spot my fault please?

```
            //TEMP

            int ax = 10;
            int bx = 20;
            int cx = 30;

            // WRITE TO DATABASE

            // Create the database connections
            string testConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kronix\Documents\users.accdb");
            OleDbConnection testDBConn = new OleDbConnection(testConnString);

            //  Populate users database into user / pass lists and compare login credentials
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (A, B, C) VALUES (@test1, @test2, @test3)";

                // add named paramaters
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                {
                    new OleDbParameter("@test1", ax),
                    new OleDbParameter("@test2", bx),
                    new OleDbParameter("@test3", cx),

                });


                cmd.Connection = testDBConn;
                testDBConn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("DONE!");
                testDBConn.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("ERROR 101: Unable to complete database entry\n");
            }
        }
```

This has had my crawling walls for the last 2 hours .... any help is appreciated.

Comment: "It's not working" is never enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Arrrrgghhhh, ok so found out my problem was that I was accessing the WRONG database.  What a silly lad.   Anyway, hopethis helps someone somehow ... even if you just get a "Ugh! Another newb!" chuckle out of it.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: If you are done, mark the question as Answered. You can select your own answer.